# A norm in the $C^1$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> How do I prove that a norm defined by 
>   $$\left\Vert f\right\Vert =\left|f(0)\right|+\int_{0}^{1}\left|f'(x)\right|dx$$  is a norm in the $C^1[0,1]$ for functions of class $C^1$?

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$, how can you integrate $\lvert f\rvert$ from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: The first step is to ask yourself, "What is the definition of a norm?" If you know the definition of a norm, you may check the certain conditions required to pass.

Comment: yeah, that $\pi$ felt bad from the start, probably someone miss-typed the problem before I got it

Comment: Recall the axioms of a norm, i.e. the requirements a mapping $\| \cdot \|: C^1[0,1] \times C^1[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ needs to fulfil in order to be called a *norm* (just as @Decaf-Math mentioned) and then try to establish these requirements for your norm $\| \cdot \|$.

Comment: Please tell me if I got it right: $\left\Vert f+g\right\Vert =\left|f(0)+g(0)\right|+\int_{0}^{1}\left|f'(x)+g'(x)\right|dx\leq\left|f(0)\right|+\left|g(0)\right|+\int_{0}^{1}\left|f'(x)\right|+\left|g'(x)\right|dx$ $\left\Vert af\right\Vert =\left|af(0)\right|+\int_{0}^{1}\left|af'(x)\right|dx=|a||f(0)|+|a|\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx =|a|\Vert f \Vert$ $\Vert f\Vert=0\iff f(0)=0\wedge\int_{0}^{1}|f'(x)|dx=0\iff f(0)=0\wedge f'(x)=0\iff f(x)=0$

Comment: The first two axioms are correct, for the third one ($\| \cdot \|$ is positive definite), see Chinnapparaj R's answer below.

Comment: I edit this question. Actually the upper limit of integral  $\pi$ does't make sense. so I change $\pi$ to $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All axioms are easy to verify except this one:$$\vert\vert f \vert\vert=0 \Longleftrightarrow f=0$$

Assume $\vert\vert f \vert\vert=0$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $\int_0^1 \vert f'(x)\vert dx=0$

Take $g(x)=\vert f'(x) \vert$ and note that $g$ is non-negative and $\int_0^1 g(x) dx=0$. Suppose $g \neq 0$ . Now use continuity of $g$ to prove there exist an interval $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ such that $g(x) >0 ,\;\forall x \in [a,b]$.

Now, $$\int_0^1 g(x) dx\geq\int_a^b g(x) dx>0$$ a contradiction! so $g$ must be a zero function! 
Hence $f'(x)=0$ and so $f$ is constant. But $f(o)=0$ implies $f$ is a zero function

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about that one axiom!